# Can I preview LWC component locally in VS Code while building the html?

Tags: lightning-web-components

I would like to see a preview of LWC component HTML while building the component. Is there a way to see html preview of this? Normal html preview extensions work only for html not LWC specific tags for components.

Comment: But you may not be able to fetch data from apex, you may be only restricted to view the UI skeleton.

Answer (score 1):

Check out Salesforce Extensions for Visual Studio Code [Local Development (Beta)](https://developer.salesforce.com/tools/vscode/en/localdev/lwclocaldev).

Comment: that project is dead as a doornail. Salesforce has always made sure to make life of developers as difficult as possible. They outdone themselves this time.

Answer (score 1):

Figured since this is the top google search, I would point anyone else who finds this to the LWC dev server plugin and salesforce's [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/tools/vscode/en/localdev/set-up-lwc-local-dev) around it.

sfdx plugins:install @salesforce/lwc-dev-server